# resubmitting to App Store, should I increase version number or build in xcode?

Tags: xcode

My first attempt was rejected and I fixed the reasons Apple gave me. Before I go through the whole archive/upload process again, should I increase the version number or build number of the app in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to increase the build number; the version number corresponds to what version your software is at.

So, you can upload "MyApp 1.0" with a Version of 1.0, and as high of a build number as you need for however many builds you've tested.

Comment: fantastic, if I can confirm this works in a few min I'll mark this as the answer